# Suppressing Report Data On Condition using Count

Tags: visual-studio-2010, count, crystal-reports, suppress

I am trying to suppress data on Report but its not happening the way I want it is there any other way to do this:

My requirement :
I've transactions like Last Balance,Investment, Redemption etc

I want to suppress Last Balance if there are any other transactions in record. 
and if there is no any other transaction then I want to show Last Balance.

For Example:
Date Transaction Units Amount

```
            30-01-2014 Last Balance   1.000   50,000
            01-02-2014 Investment     2.000   100,000
```

In this example Investment is in record so I don't want Last Balance in this case.

But if there are only Last Balance Transactions

```
            30-01-2014 Last Balance   1.000   50,000
            01-02-2014 Last Balance   2.000   100,000
            02-02-2014 Last Balance   3.000   150,000
```

Then I want this Last Balance I tried using Count :

> local numbervar myCount;
>
> if {FundTransactionReport.TSD_TRXNAME} = 'Last Balance'
>   then myCount := 0
>
> else
>
> myCount := Count({FundTransactionReport.TSD_TRXNAME},{@Group1});

and then comparing this count

> whileprintingrecords;
>
> if {@Count} <= 0 then
>   (
>   if {FundTransactionReport.TSD_TRXNAME} = 'Last Balance'
>   then true
>   )

it is correctly working when there are other transactions suppressing last balance but how can I handle this suppress when there are no any other transactions except Last Balance?